# Inheritance from non-protocol type 'Tip'

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to use TipKit in my application. As soon as I want to define the struct, the message "Inheritance from non-protocol type 'Tip'" appears. Does Anyone know, how to fix that?

```
import TipKit

struct FavoriteBackyardTip: Tip { <------------ Inheritance from non-protocol type 'Tip'

    var title: Text {
        Text("Save as a Favorite").foregroundColor(.indigo)
    }
    
    var message: Text {
        Text("Your favorite backyards always appear at the top of the list.")
    }
    
    var asset: Image {
        Image(systemName: "star")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Did you declare a `Tip` type somewhere else in your app?

Comment: make sure `Tip` is a protocol. Also, consider changing `FavoriteBackyardTip` to class.

Comment: I think it's fine to have a struct conforms Tip protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sweeper said in his comment, you must have another `Tip` declaring somewhere. You may consider changing that named type because it's the same name as the system one. Or add the module name before `Tip`.

```swift
struct FavoriteBackyardTip: TipKit.Tip {
   ...
}
```